# Iterate each cell in a specific column in csv by using pandas in Python

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a CSV file, I want to iterate each row of only **one** specific column.

Let's say, the column name is "phrase", there are 1000 rows in this column as follows:

| ID | phrase |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | apple |
| 2 | banana |
| ... | ... |

How can I iterate each cell in this column?

I have tried to use:

```
df = pd.read_csv('myfile.csv', usecols=[1])
for row in df:
    print(row)
```

I only get value of the first row of this column, not iterate each row, as follows:

```
Current output:
phrase
```

```
Desired output:
phrase # with or without this one are all OK
apple
banana
```

Does anyone know how can I get the desired result? Thanks!

Comment: Why do you convert `row` to list? `list('abc')` is `['a', 'b', 'c']`. Also, do you -really- need `pandas`? can you just use the `csv` module directly? Also2, you can just do `df.phrase.tolist()`

Comment: Hi @DeepSpace, thanks for your comment. I actually do not have to use pandas, if so,  which csv module I can use? It is my first time to deal with csv file.

Comment: I wrote a proper answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't convert `row` to list. `list('abc')` is `['a', 'b', 'c']`.

The simplest way to achieve this is with `df.phrase.tolist()`:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('myfile.csv')
print(df.phrase.tolist())
```

outputs

```py
['apple', 'banana']
```

Since you commented that you don't actually have to use `pandas`, this can be done with the built-in [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) module which might be a bit less overwhelming for a beginner:

```py
import csv

with open('myfile.csv') as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f)
    phrases = [line['phrase'] for line in reader]

print(phrases)
```

Also outputs

```py
['apple', 'banana']
```